# Update master table with update table while no obs in master table SAS

Tags: sas

I have two datasets: base (master table) updateX (updated table which might contain new observation)

```
data base;
    input Field1 $ Field2 $ Field3 $ Field4 $;
    datalines;
F 0001 20160501 ABC
NF 0001 20160502 CDF
NF 0002 20160601 ABC
NF 0002 20160602 CDF
    ;
run;

data updateX;
    input Field1 $ Field2 $ Field3 $ Field4 $;
    datalines;
F 0001 20160502 CDF
F 0002 20160602 CDF
F 0003 20160603 CDF
    ;
run;
```

My desired output

```
F 0001 20160501 ABC
F 0001 20160502 CDF
NF 0001 20160502 CDF
F 0002 20160602 CDF
F 0003 20160603 CDF
```

My effort:

```
data base;
    modify base updateX;
    by Field2 Field3;
run;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With MODIFY you need to tell SAS to REPLACE or OUTPUT depending on if the records are matched or not.

```
data base;
   modify base updatex;
   by field2 field3;
   if _iorc_ eq 0 then replace;
   else do;
      output;
      _error_=0;
      end;
   run;
```

It is easier if you can create a new data set using UPDATE.  With update the matching records are updated and then output (replaced) and new records from the transaction file are output.

```
data ubase;
   update base updatex;
   by field2 field3;
   run;
```

Comment: Actually MERGE might be better than UPDATE if you want your new records to totally replace the matching old records. With UPDATE you need to take extra steps to force a value to missing.

Comment: As i got 3 gb data every month and i need to update the data daily. Which syntax has highest efficient? Thanks again

Comment: @useR you will need to do some research and testing.  UPDATE will create a new data so that is probably not what you want.  Is the master indexed by the Key fields?  You need to read the documentation on MODIFY thoroughly.

Comment: limitation for update is we need to sort the data first which i would like to avoid.